Addition subloor 3/4" lower than existing subfloor
We just had an addition added on to our home. The plywood subfloor for the addition is 3/4" lower than the existing plywood subfloor of main house. The contractor failed to notice and house was completely built out (bathrooms, bedrooms, etc) and the flooring installed without any leveling so there is a hump between old and new. What would you do about this contractor? We withheld final payment so far. We will have to disclose this defect to any subsequent buyer but don't really want to have the floor torn up again right now as we have just finished and are living in the addition.

Hi Mike; pictures would help. Probably a transition piece of some kind between the uneven floors.

It is hard to not notice a 3/4 inch dip/drop.  It will depend on the contract if this could be a lawyer problem to fix, or be nice and have the contractor use an easy fix, like a transition piece to smooth the hump out.

"Failed to notice" equals "lazy MFer" in this case.

Unless noted in the contract any normal man would expect the flooring in the new addition and the original house to match.
A transition can alleviate the difference in height. However unless this is something that was expected and noted to be needed, the contractor should be responsible for making the floor level match.
My biggest concern is, how did this get to a finished state without something being noticed.  Legal advice is probably needed here.

A 3/4 inch difference should  have at least one face plant or a snub toe.
